# Javascript: Creating dictionary array using variables for keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, variables, key-value

I am trying to create a dictionary from some lists using the .push() method.

The result I am trying to achieve is:

```
{
  "departTo": {
    1: 1.159,
    2: 4.156,
    3: 9.185,
    3: 10.158,
    4: 2.158
  },
  "departTo": {
    1: 2.586,
    2: 5.518,
    3: 11.584,
    3: 7.819,
    4: 3.991
  }
}
```

Below is a sample of code of what I am trying to do:

```
console.group("Running Script 1...");

var select_array = [];
var arrive_from, info

var selection_type = ["departTo", "arriveFrom"];
var data_lists_depart = [[1, 1.159], [2, 4.156], [3, 9.185], [4, 10.158], [5, 2.158]];
var data_lists_arrive = [[1, 2.586], [2, 5.518], [3, 11.584], [4, 7.819], [5, 3.991]];

selection_type.forEach(function (selection, i) {
    console.log("selection", i + ": ", selection);
    if (selection === "departTo") data_lists = data_lists_depart;
    else if (selection === "arriveFrom") data_lists = data_lists_arrive;
    data_lists.forEach(function (data_list, ii) {
        console.log("   data_list", ii + ": ", data_list);
        key = data_list[0];
        val = data_list[1];
        select_array.push({selection: {key: val}});
    })
})
console.log("select_array: ", select_array);

console.groupEnd("Running Script 1...");
```

The result I am getting from the above code is:

```
[
  {"selection": {"key": 1.159}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 4.156}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 9.185}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 10.158}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 2.158}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 2.586}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 5.518}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 11.584}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 7.819}}, 
  {"selection": {"key": 3.991}}
]
```

Any assistance in getting this into the format I need will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Keys have to be unique. You can't have two `3` keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` with `array#map` to generate your result object.

```js
const selection_type = ["departTo", "arriveFrom"],
      data_lists_depart = [[1, 1.159], [2, 4.156], [3, 9.185], [4, 10.158], [5, 2.158]],
      data_lists_arrive = [[1, 2.586], [2, 5.518], [3, 11.584], [4, 7.819], [5, 3.991]],
      values = [data_lists_depart, data_lists_arrive],
      result = Object.fromEntries(selection_type.map((name,i) => ([name, Object.fromEntries(values[i]) ])));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Useful code but I need the 'if' and 'else if' statements. I would like to know how to push variable values in as the key instead of the string of the variable name.

Comment: Didn't get you. Where do you need conditional statements? What will be expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution

```js
const departTo = [[1, 1.159], [2, 4.156], [3, 9.185], [4, 10.158], [5, 2.158]];
const arriveFrom = [[1, 2.586], [2, 5.518], [3, 11.584], [4, 7.819], [5, 3.991]];
const result = { 
  departTo: Object.fromEntries(departTo), 
  arriveFrom: Object.fromEntries(arriveFrom) 
};

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```